# Do skin mites reproduce on human face during night?

Tags: human-biology, skin, arachnology

I've seen this circulating on social networks:

[image]

I was wondering to what extent is it true. Do skin mites really get on the skin surface to reproduce? Why is it so?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is true that these mites exist on healthy human skin, on >98% of people, no matter the country or hygiene.

However, I'm sorry to say that this photograph is **not** the follicle mite *Demodex folliculorum*. This image has been widely circulated around the internet as *Demodex*, but it is actually the head of a silkworm, *Bombyx mori*. The above version has been modified slightly from the original, but you can see the original here: https://www.sciencephoto.com/media/720736/view/silkworm-head-sem

And here is a zoomed out version of a silkworm: https://macrocritters.wordpress.com/2012/11/26/photographing-down-the-food-web-silkworms-bombyx-mori/

You can find a **real** close-up of *Demodex* here: https://www.sciencesource.com/archive/Demodex-folliculorum-(SEM)-SS2367855.html

Comment: Is there a reference on the Demodex population spread? Also the last link is behind paywall.

Comment: Doesn't answer the main question about mite reproduction, but it *does* address the "is it true?" portion of the OP's post. Good on you for catching it. +1